# ROS Nav Stack - Obtaining correct heading at the goal without final pointturn

Tags: ros, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am using ROS Indigo with the Navigation stack on a holonomic vehicle. The planning overall seems to work

However, once the robot reaches the XY goal it does a final pointturn. Is there a way to have it plan an arc so that when the destination is reached the heading is already correct?

It also seems to now like holonomic motions. Is there a way to bias the planner to use more holonomic motions (note: the planner has holonomic set to true).

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232544/ros-nav-stack---obtaining-correct-heading-at-the-goal-without-final-pointturn/) by [dkohanba](https://answers.ros.org/users/26665/dkohanba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the first part of your question (heading), you can try setting the `global_planner`'s orientation filter to `ForwardThenInterpolate` (maybe experiment with all of them). You can read what each filter does here: [GlobalPlanner.cfg](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/global_planner/cfg/GlobalPlanner.cfg)

It looks like you'll have to use `dynamic_reconfigure` in order to set the filter.

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dkohanba](https://answers.ros.org/users/26665/dkohanba/) on 2016-04-25**:
Thanks. I will try that.